# Remove leading zeros from integer in C

Tags: c, int, decimal, octal

If I declare an integer in C as below :

```
int an_example = 000300;
```

Can I somehow "cut off" the leading zeros from an integer number? I want 000300 to be interpreted as 300.

Comment: This is an octal number in C source code, since it starts with 0. Numbers don't have zeros, only their representation may have some.

Comment: No, those leading zeroes make the number octal.

Comment: Why do you want it in that way?

Comment: Why is everyone down voting the question? This is something I hate about the people on SO. How is that not a valid question? Maybe hes a hobbyist programmer and isn't aware of Octal notation.

Comment: What is this question actually about? You want it int to be interpreted as `300` decimal, but you put in octal `300` (`192 dec`) and ask if you can drop the leading zeroes? @_@  @ffhaddad Maybe because as it is now it makes zero sense whatsoever (there is zero mention of octal). Also, http://ideone.com/H1WLUg, doesn't really hurt. There is a "soft" requirement to show minimal effort...

Comment: I wonder if stripping leading 0s can be done with a macro as in `int an_example = DROP_LEAD_0(000300);`?  Of course, code could use `#define 000300 300`, but that is an obfuscation.

Comment: Maybe OP does not understand octal, but maybe does.  IMO, OP evidently knows the literal string `000300` is not being interpreted as the value 300 and is looking for some work-around.  It appears OP has a need to show "000300" in code.  Maybe something as simple as `int an_example = 300;  // 000300`?

Answer (score 7):

If you write `0` in the start of an integer literal, it means that **the number is octal**. 300 octal is equal to 192 decimal, so you will get the value 192 from this code.

Cut off leading zeroes with the delete key on your keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

```
000300
```

This is an octal constant. It can be more concisely written as

```
0300
```

This value is equal to the decimal value 192.

If you want the decimal number 300, write

```
300
```

But do be very clear that `0300 != 300`.

In case you need something a little more concrete, try running this program. You should now be in a position to predict its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", 000300);
    printf("%d\n", 0300);
    printf("%d\n", 300);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand that numbers can be expressed in four common representations in C. Binary, Octal, Decimal, and Hexadecimal.

For example:

Binary (base 2):

0b100101100 // 300 in binary, The leading 0b together tells the compiler its a binary value (not all compilers support this).

Octal (base 8)

0300 // This is 192 in decimal. The leading 0 tells the compiler the value is octal.

Hexadecimal (base 16)

0x12C // 300 in decimal. The leading 0x tells the compiler the value is hexadecimal.

Your number:
000300 is an octal number and represents 192 in decimal because you have a leading 0. Note the superfluous leading zeros do not affect the value.

As to your question: No, you can not include leading zeros and have the compiler interpret the value as decimal.

Comment: Note that the `0b` binary notation is standardized in C++14, and is an extension to the C standard elsewhere.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler There are 3 types of people in the world: Those who divide the world in [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Binary_literals), and those who don't. :-)

Comment: @chux: 3 types?  I thought there were 10 types — those who think in binary and those who don't.

Comment: BTW: numbers can also be expressed as `integer-constant` like the 4 you presented. There are also `floating-constant` like `int a = 1e4;`, `enumeration-constant` like `int b = fred;` and `character-constant` like `int c = 'C';`.

Answer (score 2):

The way an integer is formatted for display is completely independent of the way you initialize it.

(By the way, a leading 0 on an integer constant means it's interpreted as an octal number.)

Answer (score 2):

> Can I somehow "cut off" the leading zeros from an intenger number? I want that 000300 is interpreted as 300.

Integers always have the same internal representation -- you don't worry about formatting issues like leading zeroes. As @BasileStarynkevitch pointed out in the comments, a leading `0` in an integer constant makes the compiler interpret the number as octal, or base 8. If you remove the leading zeroes from the code you provided, `an_example` will change from 300 octal (192 decimal) to 300 decimal (454 octal).

How you *display* `an_example` is another matter, and whether there are depends entirely on the format specifier you use. For example, if you want to print the number in octal but without a leading 0, you'd use the `%o` specifier:

```
printf("%o", an_example);
```

If you want to print it as a decimal number, use `%d` in place of `%o` above.

On the other hand, if you want to print it with the leading 0 to indicate octal, you'd write:

```
printf("%#o", an_example);
```